# My code works in codepen but not in website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Some part of my code doesnt work and I cant find out why. I tried piece of that to codepen and that works, later on I added whole page and it still works. But on my website doesent. Why?

Code that not works is

```
$(".hinfo").hide();
$(".hidit").on("click", function () {

   $(this).next(".hinfo").toggle();

});
```

Here at codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxmxop it toggle on the hinfo. Here at my page http://www.hriste.host-ed.me it doesnt make nothing. Why?

Edited:

If you click to "3 stops (i)" at codepen slides down div .hinfo. I have same code on my website and nothig happens.

[image]

Comment: `NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.hriste.host-ed.me/animate.css`

Comment: Removed, but still the same.

Comment: It would help if you would more clearly describe the problem.

Comment: Agree with @Pointy, I don't know what to click or how to replicate the issue you're seeing. Also do you see any Errors in your console.

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the content of script.js in a document ready function. You're binding events to the DOM before it's fully loaded.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Content here
});
```

Comment: Or just wrap it in `$(function(){ // Your code });` would work too. Also, I see you have Scripts in the head and scripts in the body that are the same. This can cause conflicts.